# How to drag an image view within a window using swift (OS X not IOS)

Tags: macos, swift, draggable

I am creating a Mac application but having difficulty when dragging a window with an image on the view. Basically I can drag the main window but unable to drag the window when clicking and dragging the image view.

I can enable dragging on the main window with "**window.movableByWindowBackground = true**" seems to work but unable to get this working when dragging the image view on the window.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to subclass your `NSImageView` and override the `mouseDownCanMoveWindow` property:

```
class MyImageView: NSImageView {

    override var mouseDownCanMoveWindow:Bool {
        return true
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Could I add the function to another class, will this work?. Sorry for my ignorance as I'm a little new to swift.

Comment: You're welcome. No need to apologize. :) You can not use this code in another class than the subclass of your imageview, if that's what you're asking. I can add details to my answer if you have issues making your subclass, but this is pretty straightforward usually.

Comment: As I'm currently just experimenting, I have created a new swift file then added the above code, added the class to the image view and works great. Would this be the most efficient way of achieving this, any suggestions or code snippets would be beneficial at this time. Thank You.

Comment: This is the most efficient way I know to do this. There's other ways, like redraw the window manually following the mouse cursor (I've done it in an app where I could not subclass the image view) but it's cumbersome and hacky. Overriding this property like in my answer is the right choice for you, in my opinion. :)

Comment: The way you suggested is just what I need, I was just wondering if this could be done the same way without having a separate class file, but not to worry if this is the best way of achieving this. Thanks..